# Best way to pass parameters to jQuery's .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a difference in passing parameters to `.load`

```
$("#myDiv").load("myScript.php?var=x&var2=y&var3=z")
```

vs

```
$("#myDiv").load("myScript.php", {var1:x, var2:y, var3:z})
```

Also, is there a size limit to how much `.load` can handle? Can
`myScript.php` return a couple hundred rows of data without issue?

Answer (score 43):

In the first case, the data are passed to the script via GET, in the second via POST.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback

I don't think there are limits to the data size, but the completition of the remote call will of course take longer with great amount of data.

Comment: From my experience there is a limit the size of the GET in MSIE.

Comment: The limit is IE is 256 bytes (roughly 2048 characters).

Answer (score 30):

As Davide Gualano has been told. 
This one

```
$("#myDiv").load("myScript.php?var=x&var2=y&var3=z")
```

use GET method for sending the request, and this one

```
$("#myDiv").load("myScript.php", {var:x, var2:y, var3:z})
```

use POST method for sending the request. But any limitation that is applied to each method (post/get) is applied to the alternative usages that has been mentioned in the question.

For example: url length limits the amount of sending data in GET method.

Comment: I didn't find out why my answer has been marked by minus one. This is the exact deference in the current implementation of jQuery. Although my description was a little complicated and I tried to make it clear.

Comment: I presume the initial downvotes were because your late answer very much mirrored the advice given by Davide many years earlier.