# How to pass javascript variable in jquery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm using jquery's .load function to load a page in a container , but I need to pass some parameters with the url,  javascript variables hold the value of the parameter

```
    var data = "xyz";
$("#toggleText").load("inner/playlist.php",{name:data});
```

Comment: Your code seems fine! However, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263962/best-way-to-pass-parameters-to-jquerys-load.

Comment: Your `.load` will send request to `inner/playlist.php?name=xyz`.

Comment: however it is not sending the request

Comment: does your code hit that line? How do you know that the request is not *sent* ?

Comment: Also `$("#toggleText")` must return an jQuery object.

Comment: Are you using $_GET['name'] or $_POST['name'] in playlist.php?

Comment: Oh I was using $_GET , Thanks jan267

Comment: first place to start is in browser console for errors thrown and to inspect the actual request to see if it is made, data transfered etc? Without knowing if problem is client or server side is a stab in the dark trying to guess at problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its always good idea to use quotes for the param names.

```
$("#toggleText").load("inner/playlist.php",{'name':data});
```

also, try to put the callback function to check it it actually does anything:

```
$("#toggleText").load("inner/playlist.php",{'name':data}, function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: quotes for object keys are irrelevant if no special characters or spaces involved