# How to receive parameters sent using jquery.load(url)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am sending params using jquery.load(loadUrl). My loadUrl is : 
${baseUrl}/1.jsp?a=1&b=2

How can i receive these params a and b in 1.jsp?

This question is followup question for [Best way to pass parameters to jQuery's .load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263962/best-way-to-pass-parameters-to-jquerys-load).

Comment: They're normal URL query parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
String a = request.getParameter("a");
String b = request.getParameter("b");
%>
```

You can also use them directly in EL:
`${param.a} ${param.b}` or `${param['a']} ${param['b']}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
    var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
        var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
           if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
               return KeyValuePair[1];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are GET parameter. you can simply use following in [JSP Scriptlets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html)

```
<%= request.getParameter("a") %>
<%= request.getParameter("b") %>
```

You can also use Use EL (JSP Expression Language):

```
${param.a}
${param.b}
```