# Javascript variable with ajax-php variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax call to an external php file "commentS.php" that refreshes every 3 seconds. However. I expected to just use the variable in the hidden input field (name="idd") and expected it to just reflect on the "commentS.php", but, it does not. What I want to achieve is to have the variable "idd" echoed on the "commentS.php" page as a variable to be used in a mysql query. I did the document write on the commentS.php but it just shows a white page with the variable number that is "idd" when the ajax call is made.

```
<input type="hidden" name="idd" value="<?php echo $row['story_id']; ?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var named = "<?php echo $idd; ?>";
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function () {
$('#content').load('commentS.php')
}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Any help would be great, a read, anything.
I am very new to js and ajax altogether. thanks

Comment: Seems like you need to POST a form to comments.php rather than just loading it via GET.  How is comments.php set up to retrieve the idd value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to pass parameters to jQuery's .load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263962/best-way-to-pass-parameters-to-jquerys-load)

Comment: If mixing php and javascript that way is your solution, then you are most likely asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#content').load('commentS.php?idd=<?php echo $idd; ?>')
```

In commentS.php you have to do this in the beginning :

```
$idd = $_GET['idd']
```

Comment: You likely need a cache buster too

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Sami your way does work, 
HOWEVER $('#content').load('commentS.php?idd=<?php echo $idd; ?>') somehow  the echo within the javascript "<?php echo $idd; ?>" doesn't echo the value. If I just put a numerical value in then I get the result I desire, it just however doesn't print. Is there a way to get the php result as a javascript variable that can be added after .load('commentS.php?idd=(RIGHT HERE). thanks so much for your help been at this all day yesterday without avail.

Comment: replace <?php echo $idd; ?> with <?php echo $row['story_id']; ?>

Comment: thank you so much Sami, everything now works like I want it too. wish I had three hands to give you three thumbs up.

Comment: u're welcome :)  As @Quentin said, this method is very dangerous ! In your PHP you have to double check the value ! If it's an ID you have to cast it : $idd = (int) $_GET['idd']

Comment: ok will do, now I have another issue, I have another script I am working on but instead of using the GET method which works perfect from the way you helped I am now using POST and it just doesn't echo the form value.  I am trying to pass this through  { formdata.append("imagetitle", ' <?php echo $_POST["image_title"]; ?>'); } but it doesn't show the form value at all. is there a work around?

Comment: it i put the variable in a string say image_title = "this is the image title"; then it parses over like i want to. however $_POST["image_title"]; after inputted text carries nothing.